# Adding value of one cell with previous value of same cell if value of another cell matches in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, counter

Here is my data in sheet1 of excel:

---

### A        B

---

A1          20

---

A2          2

---

A1          2

---

A3          3

---

Consider the above in an excel sheet. Column A contains duplicate keys and Column B contains quantity. my requirement is, I need a function in Excel which can add values of B for unique values of column A.

so output should be

Sheet 2:

---

### A B

---

A1          22

---

A2          2

---

A3          3

---

Has anyone worked with such a requirement?

thanks.

Comment: This would be a good use for a pivot table.  Using SUMIF won't reduce it to only unique values of A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in sheet 2 place the following formula into cell `B2` and drag down:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!B:B)
```

**Details**

This says to check if column A from sheet1 has the key to my left.

If it does then return the sum of all the corresponding cells in column B that meet the requirement.